# MySQL WHERE doesn't work properly

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a category.php page which shows all the articles in a given category ($tagname) where enabled=1. When an article has only one tag (and two empty ones) then everything is fine. The article will be shown on this category.php page (when enabled is set to 1). However, if at least two tags are filled then the article will show up on the category.php page where tag2=$tagname or if tag3=$tagname - no matter what the enabled field contains (1 for enabled, 2 for disabled)!

Bottom line - why does it show up even though enabled is set to 2 for that article?

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
WHERE enabled=1
  AND tag1='$tagname'
  OR tag2='$tagname'
  OR tag3='$tagname'

enabled, int
tag1, varchar(30)
tag2, varchar(30)
tag3, varchar(30)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help! It works proper good now! :)
(tag1='$tagname' OR tag2='$tagname' OR tag3='$tagname')

Answer (score 2):

`AND` has high precedence over `OR` and hence in your query

First `enabled=1 and tag1='$tagname'` is evaluated and then
its result is compared to next `OR` expression and so on...
Unless you separate `AND` conditions with `OR` conditions properly, out put would be as unexpected.

Change your query as below:

```
SELECT * FROM articles 
 WHERE enabled=1 
   AND (tag1='$tagname' OR tag2='$tagname' OR tag3='$tagname')
```

**Refer to**: [***Operator Precedence***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operator-precedence.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
WHERE enabled=1
  AND (tag1='$tagname'
       OR tag2='$tagname'
       OR tag3='$tagname')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query.

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
WHERE enabled=1
  AND (tag1='$tagname'
       OR tag2='$tagname'
       OR tag3='$tagname')
```

Answer (score 1):

try to separate your conditions

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
WHERE enabled=1
  AND (tag1='$tagname'
       OR tag2='$tagname'
       OR tag3='$tagname')
```

so now it will be check result where enabled=1 and any tag result ture from 3